# Toggle fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullscreen

I want a simple function for toggling full screen. Here is what I've written:

```
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    var elem = document.documentElement,
      request = elem.requestFullscreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen,
      exit = document.exitFullscreen || document.msExitFullscreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen;
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
      request.call(elem);
    } else {
      exit.call(document);
    }
  }
```

Any better or simple solution?
Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Toggling_fullscreen_mode

Comment: I think my code is simpler than that..